# Linear or quadratic damping term in Euler's equation?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, friction, viscosity, gas

In the Euler equation with frictional damping
$$
\begin{cases}
\rho_t + (\rho u)_x = 0 \\
(\rho u)_t + (\rho u^2 + P(\rho))_x = \color{red}{-\alpha \rho u}
\end{cases}
$$
sometimes I see a different friction term (to replace the one in red):
$$-\alpha \rho u |u|.$$

- What's the difference between these from the point of view of modelling?
- Are there any differences in the large time asymptotics for there different damping terms?

Comment: The right way to do dynamical friction in a fluid is to use the Navier-Stokes equations, which introduces higher derivatives.  However, even there the long-term regularity of the solutions is a famously unsolved problem.

Comment: @Buzz Thanks. But among the linear or the quadratic choice, which is more relevant to irregular flows?

Comment: Is this a 1-dimensional flow (say, flow through a capillary with walls providing the frictional force)? Because otherwise, the momentum flux density does not look correct. In more usual notation, in more than 1-d, we have the following equation for momentum conservation (without friction) : $\partial_t(\rho u_i) + \nabla_j(\rho u_j u_i + P\delta_{ij}) = 0 $, which reduces to your LHS in 1-d

Comment: @Buzz: If this is indeed, as I suspect, a 1-d fluid, how exactly would the derivative expansion work?

Answer (score 0):

for a vertically thrown ball, the drag force could be either linear or quadratic in the speed. Which type of drag correspond to specific ranges of the 
Reynolds number ($Re<1$ and $103<Re<2105$, respectively)   and do not hold outside these intervals.